# Laravel Socialite - Avatar is to slow

Tags: laravel, avatar

I am using the Laravel 5.0 with the Socialite Library. Everything works fine except i am a little disappointment with the size of the avatar.
Is it possible to get a bigger avatar?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code of Socialite https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/2.0/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php

You can see at line 91 that the url for the avatar appends a static `?type=normal` at the end. The Facebook graph API documentation says that you can request an avatar size using an `ENUM` or custom `width/height` so you can modify line 91 and append an `ENUM` or custom `width/height` like `?type=large`

More details can be found in the Facebook graph API documentation.

However, this is only for the Facebook driver so you will need to dig in a similar fashion for other providers. If their APIs do not allow such freedom as in the case of Facebook then you will need to do with the avatar being returned.

**Updated March 12, 2015**

Do not customize the original Socialite package, fork the repository and then make the change. You can then plug your forked repository into your project and also send a pull request to the original author in case he thinks its worth having the functionality you have implemented. Also, your forked repository will not be updated/maintained as is the case with the original package. In case you choose to update to the new package, your changes will be lost.

Comment: While your answer is correct (and in this case the only solution), the thing to keep in mind is that it's generally bad to change the packages directly, because any update to the package will overwrite your changes.

Answer (score 2):

## Fix for Facebook / Google / Twitter Small Avatar Photo

I have created this helper method on my AuthController

```
public function getBigAvatar($user, $provider)
{
    return ($provider == "google") ? $user->getAvatar()."0" : $user->avatar_original;
}
```

**AND THIS IS HOW I CALL IT:**

```
 $user = Socialite::driver( $provider )->user();
 $userPhoto = $this->getBigAvatar($user, $provider);
```

So Simple in case its Google, Well just append 0 to the end of the url and well get a 500px avatar.  And for twitter and Facebook, The Providers already offers an avatar_original attribute as seen in

**FacebookProvider.php**

```
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
    $avatarUrl = $this->graphUrl.'/'.$this->version.'/'.$user['id'].'/picture';

    return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => null, 'name' => isset($user['name']) ? $user['name'] : null,
        'email' => isset($user['email']) ? $user['email'] : null, 'avatar' => $avatarUrl.'?type=normal',
        'avatar_original' => $avatarUrl.'?width=1920',
    ]);
}
```

**TwitterProvider.php**

```
   return $instance->map([
        'id' => $user->uid, 'nickname' => $user->nickname,
        'name' => $user->name, 'email' => $user->email, 'avatar' => $user->imageUrl,
        'avatar_original' => str_replace('_normal', '', $user->imageUrl),
    ]);
```

Since Google does not map this, And gets a default 50px image, we simple change it to 500px with is great for avatar.

WORKED PERFECT FOR ME, LET ME KNOW IF IT HELPS YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Just append your required size after the ?type=normal like this:

graph.facebook.com/v2.2/{user}/picture?type=normal **&width=76&height=76**

this will override the type=normal

Answer (score 0):

For use original avatars size from Facebook and Google:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider){
$userData = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
$user = new User;
...
```

Google:

```
$user->avatar = preg_replace('/\?sz=[\d]*$/', '', $userData->avatar);
```

Facebook:

```
$user->avatar = $userData->avatar_original;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I have came up with

```
    if($file = $user->getAvatar()) {
        if ($provider == 'google') {
            $file = str_replace('?sz=50', '', $file);
        } elseif ($provider == 'twitter') {
            $file = str_replace('_normal', '', $file);
        } elseif ($provider == 'facebook') {
            $file = str_replace('type=normal', 'type=large', $file);
        }
    }
```

Happy coding everyone :)

This is basically just replacement or a part of avatar image URL so it would return the bigger one.

**getAvatar()** function return the image url, so I stored it in variable $file

And depending on the provider url structure is different, so for each provider you need to change image URL string accordingly

**Google**
remove '?sz=50' from image url string

**Twitter**
remove '_normal' from image url string

**Facebook**
replace 'type=normal' with 'type=large' in image url string

Comment: Please explain the code, don't just show it. It will raise the answer's value

Comment: sorry, here you are

Answer (score 0):

here is another simpler way for the avatar

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    // dd($user);

    if ($user) {
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);

        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    return 'something went wrong';
}

private function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
{
    $found = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();

    if ($found) {
        return $found;
    }

    // so the default is G+, change according to your needs
    $avatar = str_replace('?sz=50', '', $user->avatar);

    if ($provider == 'facebook' || $provider == 'twitter') {
        $avatar = $user->avatar_original;
    }

    return User::create([
        'username'        => $user->name,
        'email'           => $user->email,
        'avatar'          => $avatar,
        'provider'        => $provider,
        'provider_id'     => $user->id,
    ]);
}
```

this way u dont change ur code much and easier for maintenance ,

however for some reason the facebook avatar doesnt show up in my app , plz if anyone can help i would deeply appreciate it.

here is my the current fb avatar link i get

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/xxxxxxxxxxx/picture?width=1920

and the view

`<img class="user-avatar" src="{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="user avatar">`